# jQuery cookie and session rotation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, cookies

I am having a issue with jquery cookie extension to save state on active menu.
 I am using the code bellow to set cookie value on click and get the cookie value on every page load. After 2 or 3 requests the cokkie gets duplicated in chrome developer tools and i get the incorrect value. Could this be because of FuelPHP framework session rotation and how can i overcome this issue without coding this in php and using ajax. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sidebar .sub-menu > a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $.cookie("sidebar_active", $("#sidebar li.active").prop("id"), { expires: 7, path:'/' });
});

    if( $.cookie("sidebar_active") ){
        $('#'+$.cookie("sidebar_active")).addClass("active").addClass("open");
    }
    else $('#sidebar_menu_1').addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect value"?

Comment: when session rotation oucurres a new cookie with same name, same path and domain gets created.

Comment: I don't really know what can happen, but could you simply do a little test that is checking your cookies, and if your cookie doesn't exist, create it, if it exists, just do nothing ?